# Report on child objects without parent in MD relationship

Tags: joined-reports

I have `Object Parent` and `Object Child` in Salesforce.

Both are set as 'reportable'. When i try to create reports, i only see `Object Parents` and `Object Parents with Object Children`.

I want to run the report on `Object Child` only without `Object Parent`.

Is that possible without switching the relationship to lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sfdcfox, I discovered that the answer is `Yes`, you just need to create a 'Custom Report Type'. There, all objects are available (that are marked 'Reportable') and you can select just the child object.

Answer (score 1):

No. Detail records **cannot** exist without parents, so by definition, you cannot report on a child-without-parent report in a Master-Detail relationship (P.S. if there were such orphans, you should report this as a bug to Salesforce Technical Support).

Comment: I really don't see how it is `by definition, you cannot report on a child-without-parent report in a Master-Detail relationship`. Sure, it can't exist without parent which is why i used it (so parent is deleted and all children are deleted). But when i am reporting, why does master come into play at all?

My specific problem is that i have a whole chain of objects in MD and the level i need to report at the SF reporting does not show me the relevant fields. :/

Comment: @zaitsman I don't know the "why", just that this is how Salesforce operates. If you don't see the fields you need, you'll need a [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5) to get the data you need.

Comment: actually, thanks for pointing me in the right direction - using custom report types i am able to create a report on just child object as i originally wanted!